# Meteor, how to fix to a npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

So, I'm using a npm package in a meteor app. It's imported in a .npm directory, and I want to add a fix to the package.

I could send the fix to the author of the package, but that will take a certain time to be pushed.
I could copy paste the whole fixed code in my project but this looks a bit dirty.

So is there a way/best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fork the repository and apply the updates, then use the git of your repository in your smart.json file e.g the below for 'meteor router'

```
{
     packages : {
         "router" : {
             git : "https://github.com/hypno2000/meteor-router.git"
         }
}
```

The original repository is at `https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git` so meteorite will use the fork instead but keep intact everything else such as dependencies but use your fork where you tell it to.

Then use `mrt update` to fetch the fork

Should the author accept the push request, just remove the `git:` line and do `mrt update` again to resume using the original package

Comment: Looks an awesome method. Actually it's not exactly my case but maybe we can do something similar. I'm developing a package depending an on npm package I want to fix : in the package.js I have this line Npm.depends({npm_package_name_I_want_to_fix: "1.24.1" });

Comment: Ahhh! Theres a hidden .npm directory that you could install the package in manually via `npm install packagename@githubrepository` (i think) or `npm install git://github.com/v....git`

Comment: Talking about this .npm directory, if I make a modification in a file from this dir, can it be overwritten without notification by meteor / meteorite?

Comment: It shouldn't do an update, until you clear the directory. Meteor thinks the npm package is installed and wont update it. You need to be a bit careful with meteorite though, because it can clear the .npm directory (I think) when you do mrt update. If you want, you could just edit the files in there too, until the authors accept your push.

Comment: Thx so much, very valuable info.